# Issue with matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am working on a small practice program to get better with python and the matplotlib module. This program has no real world uses, I just wanna understand where i went wrong

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def main():
    getTotal()
def getTotal():
    BTC=int(input('How much would you like to allocate to BTC as a percentage: '))
    ETH=int(input('How much would you like to allocate to ETH as a percentage: '))
    LTC=int(input('How much would you like to allocate to LTC as a percentage: '))
    values=[BTC,ETH,LTC]
    if BTC+ETH+LTC>100:
        print('That was too much, try again')
        getTotal()
        del values
    slices=[BTC,ETH,LTC]
    plt.pie(values,labels=slices)
    plt.title('Crypto Allocations')
    plt.show()
main()
```

and it is throwing this error

```
 File "C:/Users/Liam/ranodm.py", line 30, in getTotal
    plt.pie(values,labels=slices)

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'values' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: If you call `values` after `del values` is evaluated you get `UnboundLocalError` because `values` is no more...

Comment: @PauloScardine has the point: "values" is no more in the scope of your function because you applied del before calling the plot.

Comment: @PauloScardine was also correct, i fixed that then got to the answer i marked as correct below when that error occured

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html) the values you're passing in the label parameter have to be `A sequence of strings providing the labels for each wedge`.
So, the value of slices has to be `slices=['BTC','ETH','LTC']`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def main():
    getTotal()
def getTotal():
    BTC=int(input('How much would you like to allocate to BTC as a percentage: '))
    ETH=int(input('How much would you like to allocate to ETH as a percentage: '))
    LTC=int(input('How much would you like to allocate to LTC as a percentage: '))
    if BTC+ETH+LTC>100:
        print('That was too much, try again')
        getTotal()
    else:
        values=[BTC,ETH,LTC]
        slices=['BTC','ETH','LTC'] #I assume that you want strings here
        plt.pie(values,labels=slices)
        plt.title('Crypto Allocations')
        plt.show()
main()
```